# z3 usage problem in java and strange error

Tags: z3

I am using Z3 for the constraints check, and I am currently use the java Z3 package.

What I am doing is that and this is my java code:

```
    Context context = new Context();
    Solver s=context.mkSolver();
    IntExpr i=context.mkIntConst("i");
    IntExpr zero=context.mkInt(1);//int i;
    BoolExpr initial=context.mkEq(i,zero);//i=0;
    IntExpr one=context.mkInt(1); //initial 1
    ArithExpr ipp=context.mkAdd(i,one);//i+1
    BoolExpr ippResult=context.mkEq(i,ipp);//i=i+1
    BoolExpr gtI=context.mkGe(i,zero);


    s.add(initial);
    s.add(ippResult);
    s.add(gtI);

    System.out.println(s+"\n\n");
 
    System.out.println(s.check());
```

And here is the output I have

```
  (declare-fun i () Int)
  (assert (= i 1))
  (assert (= i (+ i 1)))
  (assert (>= i 1))

   UNSATISFIABLE
```

So I don't know why z3 returns that it is not satisfiable? Since i+1>=1 actually, it is so strange. I don't know what code I am writing wrongly. Thanks!

Comment: Your program is incomplete. You said `s.add(gtI)`, but there's no definition for `gtI`. Please post the entire code you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program isn't complete; you use `gtI` but you never defined it. Probably cut-and-paste error.

In any case, your problem is nicely captured by the SMTLib portion of your output:

```
 (declare-fun i () Int)
 (assert (= i 1))
 (assert (= i (+ i 1)))
 (assert (>= i 1))
```

The second line says `i`  is `1`. Third line says `i` is equal to `i+1`. Combining these two, the solver deduces that it must be the case that `1 = 2`. Which is clearly not true, and hence you get the `UNSATISFIABLE` result.

I suspect you wanted to create a new variable and use that in creating `i+1`, perhaps `j`? But hard to opine without knowing what it is that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer. What I want to achieve is the following: i=0;i=i+1;if(i>=1) .But I don't know why it returns the Unsatisfiable error.

Comment: Thanks! It solved. But I just confused why it cannot make the old variable i equal to a new result? It seems like the old variable cannot be changed once it is actually given value? Thanks so much again for your help!

Comment: There’s no assignment in z3/smtLib. You simulate it by using new variables.

Comment: Thannk you! I understand now! Thanks for your help!